# How can i use SaveChanges() in order to save existing data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, savechanges

I just need to change some data already saved in my db in SQL.

Here is my code:

```
var userData = new MinciUsers
{
    ApplicationUserId = stringUserId,
    Name = userUnity.firstName,
    LastName = userUnity.lastName,
    DateOfBirth = date,
    Address = userUnity.address,
    CityId = null,
    CountryId = null,
    LanguageId = null,
};

dbContext.MinciUsers.Add(userData);
dbContext.SaveData();
```

When I change some of the data it throws an error because the primary key already exists.

How can I use `SaveChanges()` when I change data?

Comment: set the state of the entry to modified or rely on ChangeTracking and modify attached entries (without manually .Add ing it to the DbSet again, which will set the states to added). You can also use the .Property methods of the entries to modify, which will also work if ChangeTracking is disabled (you'll have to attach before though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to first fetch the corresponding object from the database and then change it's state by specifying the new values. Last you call `SaveChanges` on the corresponding context class to persist the changes.

For instance, if the primary key is denoted in your application as Id:

```
var minciUser = dbContext.MinciUsers.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == 1);
if(minciUser != null)
{
    // The record with Id 1 has been found. So you can change it's state.

    minciUser.ApplicationUserId = stringUserId;

    // here you will add the rest of the fields you want to update.       

    dbContext.SaveChagnes();
}
```

**Update**

Another approach ii would be to make use of [AddOrUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx):

```
var userData = new MinciUsers
{
    ApplicationUserId = stringUserId,
    Name = userUnity.firstName,
    LastName = userUnity.lastName,
    DateOfBirth = date,
    Address = userUnity.address,
    CityId = null,
    CountryId = null,
    LanguageId = null,
};

dbContext.MinciUsers.AddOrUpdate(userData);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Christos! thx for your answering!

In this case "ApplicationUserId is my Id

Comment: i remember in the back of my head i had seen years back, some kind of insert function `dbContext` had where you could directly update based on primary key. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Yes mate! thats what i need

Comment: There is a method call `AddOrUpdate`, but it needs some caution on how you will use it, http://www.michaelgmccarthy.com/2016/08/24/entity-framework-addorupdate-is-a-destructive-operation/.

Comment: @Christos interesting! the thing is i dont have the "AddOrUpdate" method

Comment: @JuanCamiloÁvila what version of Entity Framework you use? As I can see this has been introduced in Entity Framework 5.0.

Comment: solved it with this: using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

Comment: @JuanCamiloÁvila Great !

Comment: @JuanCamiloÁvila Is `ApplicationUserId` the primary key of the table? Have you ever used a sql profiler? If so, you can easily track down what query is send actually to the database to be executed and you could investigate further from this point.

Comment: @Christos Hey bud! thank you so much! ive tried your first option and its working :D you saved my life!

Comment: @JuanCamiloÁvila You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)